# Variable in Variable (?)- php loop

Tags: php, variables, loops

I'm relatively new to PHP loops, been learning them and they sure do make my life easier. However, I came across a bit of a struggle when trying to create a new variable for the PHP loop.

Background:

I declared 21 variables such as:

```
$q1W = 5;
$q2W = 10;
$q3W = 2;
```

Then I grabbed the `$_GET` (`q1`,`q2`,`q3`) variables and put them into variables with their values:

```
foreach($_GET as $qinput => $value) {
    $$qinput  = $value ;
}
```

Now, essentially, I want to turn this code:

```
$q1final = $q1 * $q1W;
$q2final = $q2 * $q2W;
$q3final = $q3 * $q3W;
```

Into a loop so I don't need to type out that all the way to 21. This is what I have thus far:

```
<?php for ($i=1; $i<=21; $i++) { 
$q.$i.final = $q.$i * $q.$i.W
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You can't concatenate when making dynamic variables the same way as normal (periods). Also, generally if you have to use dynamic variables, you're doing something wrong.

Comment: @AlexLunix You *can* concatenate strings to make dynamic variable names (see my comment on the answer below) but I agree that if "dynamic variable names" is the right answer, you're probably asking the wrong question.

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend using arrays instead of lots of variables. It makes relating your data more straightforward. For example:

```
$mults = array(
    'q1W' => 5, 
    'q2W' => 10,
    'q3W' => 2
);
$final = array();
foreach ($_GET as $qinput => $value) {
    $final[$qinput] = $mults[$qinput] * $value;
}
print_r($final);
```

Comment: This is the correct answer (+1), but for reference to the OP/future visitors, the correct syntax for using a counter as above to define a variable variable name would be use strings in braces, e.g. `${'q'.$i.'final'} = ${'q'.$i} * ${'q'.$i.'W'};`